# Xpages runtime error: 'java class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)'

Tags: java, jar, runtime-error, xpages

I am trying to call 'new XWPFDocument(inStream);' in a java class in an XPages application. The XWPFDocument class is part of the Apache POI library. However when it gets to the call to this constructor at runtime, I get the following stack trace:

11/02/2014 20:57:02   HTTP JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
11/02/2014 20:57:02   HTTP JVM:     at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getContextTypeLoader(XmlBeans.java:336)
11/02/2014 20:57:02   HTTP JVM:     at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
11/02/2014 20:57:02   HTTP JVM:     at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:134)
11/02/2014 20:57:02   HTTP JVM:     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159) ...

I have added all the necessary jar files to the 'Web Content/WEB INF/lib' folder under package explorer, and subsequently added them to the project's java build path. Am I missing something?

The code around the call is:

```
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        InputStream inStream = null;
        EmbeddedObject embeddedObj = null;
        XWPFDocument document = null;

        if (attachments.size() > 0) {
            String attachmentName = attachments.get(0).toString();
            embeddedObj = downloadDocument.getAttachment(attachmentName);
            if (embeddedObj != null) {
                inStream = embeddedObj.getInputStream();
                document = new XWPFDocument(inStream);
                inStream.close();

                document.write(outStream);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add to Domino server's `jvm/lib/security/java.policy` file

```
grant codeBase "xspnsf://server:0/<application>.nsf/WEB-INF/lib/*" {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
}
```

or put the jar files into Domino server's trusted folder `jvm/lib/ext`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to change the `java.policy` file, because those changes won't survive a software upgrade. Instead, create a `java.pol` file in the same folder and make the changes there. See also http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/java-security-in-ibm-domino/

Comment: Mark is correct but I suspect there may be issues with 9.01 and java.pol - I can't put my finger on a definite cause yet but we are having issues with 9.01 and java agents

Comment: @Fyleman001 did it finally work for you? Did you change java.policy or did you create java.pol? Would be interesting to know also for people having same issue in future. Thanks